# overloading class operators for pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

Is it even possible?

So I have

```
class Organism{
// ....
public:
   virtual std::string type(){
      return "Organism"
   }
// ....

}
```

I also have derived clases `ant`, `beetle`, witch return `"Ant"` / `"Beetle"`

I have one more class `World` where things happen.

In `World class` there are `Organism* world[20][20];`

I want to create operator that comperas `word[x][y]` to `world[x1][y1]`

I managed to create operator:

```
friend bool operator== (const Organism &lhs, const Organism &rhs){
    return lhs.type() == rhs.type();
}
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
friend bool operator== (const Organism* lhs, const Organism* rhs){
    return lhs->type() == rhs->type();
}
```

but it doesnt allow it VS13 says "Error: nonmember operator requires a parameter with class or enum type".

How to achieve this?

ps. I can't even write const after closing `)`.

Comment: No, you cannot override operators on only pointers.

Comment: @Yakk What else can I do?

Comment: @Cirvis: What is wrong with your first `operator==` (the one that uses references)? Why do you need it to be a pointer?

Comment: in class I only have `Organism* vars = new Ant` etc.

Comment: @Cirvis You can make `friend bool equal(const Organism* lhs, const Organism* rhs)` function

Comment: I would expect == with pointers to actually compare the pointers, not the objects they point to.

Comment: You could type a `*`?